# Simpler code evaluating Dickman's function?

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, code-review

I've read [here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-calculus-and-differential-equations/) that Mathematica 10 can *Obtain symbolic solutions to delay differential equations*.

Would that help in numericaly evaluating [Dickman's function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DickmanFunction.html) $\rho(u)$ ?

It is a delay differential equation defined for $u\in\mathbb R^+$ by
$$\begin{cases}
\rho(u)=1 & \text{if }0\le u\le1\\
u\cdot\rho'(u)+\rho(u-1)=0& \text{if }u>1
\end{cases}$$

---

Otherwise said, can Mathematica 10 (or something) help improve/simplify this (working) code?

```
Dickm$pr=40 (*desired ABSOLUTE (rather than relative) accuracy*);

Dickm$ex=Ceiling[Dickm$pr*Log[3,10]]+1 (*order of expansions; empirical*);

Dickm$ma=Ceiling[Dickm$ex/Log[Dickm$ex]] (*domain limit*);

(*Dickm$dv[n] approximates DickmanRho[t+n-1/2] for -1/2\[LessEqual]t\[LessEqual]1/2*)

Dickm$dv[1]=N[1,Dickm$pr+1];

Dickm$dv[n_]:=Dickm$dv[n]=Module[{u=Dickm$dv[n-1],v},v=Integrate[(u+O[\.b2]^Ceiling[Dickm$ex-n])/(\.b2+n-1/2),\.b2];(Normal[u]/.\.b2->1/2)+(Normal[v]/.\.b2->-1/2)-v];

DickmanRho[y_?NumberQ]:=Which[y<=0,1,y>Dickm$ma,N[1,y Log[10.,y]]-1,True,Normal[Dickm$dv[Ceiling[y]]]/.\.b2->y-Ceiling[y]+1/2];

(* Example use *)
DickmanRho[15]
```

Comment: Ack. I was going to suggest this: "Might want to check [this old MathGroup post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/Dec/msg00377.html)." Then I realized that was your work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes!

```
fun = NDSolve[{u ρ'[u] + ρ[u - 1] == 0, ρ[u /; u < 1] == 1}, ρ, {u, 0, 20}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 40, PrecisionGoal -> ∞, AccuracyGoal -> 40, 
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"][[1, 1, 2]];

fun[15]
(* 7.5899080042980595046528227779709126741*10^-20 *)

DickmanRho[15]
(* 7.5899080042980595047*10^-20 *)
```

It works not only in V10 (in V8 at least).

Comment: @fgrieu, I tune the options for `NDSolve` and now it works much better. However, it takes several seconds which is ~100 times slower than your clever method!

Comment: Looks like `Method` made a difference. $\;$ I wonder if we could make use the [new DSolve capabilities](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-calculus-and-differential-equations/find-symbolic-solutions-for-delay-differential-equ.html).

Comment: @fgrieu I tried `DSolve`, but it produces [very huge formulas](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FMFXG.png) so we have to manually simplify and rounding them. But it is what you have already done...